# How can I use rich text in Notepad++?

Tags: plugins, notepad++

I like Notepad++, but sometimes I need some words set in bold or cursive, change font size, etc.

Is that possible in Notepad++?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NP++ itself doesn't allow rich text, and most likely no plugin could add this functionality.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331753/topic/3445473

Comment: It DOES allow rich text; you just have to go to Settings menu --> Style Configurator (https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/167/no-way-to-change-editor-s-font) 
Only problem is it affects it globally or per file(I think..still experimenting). But it still does not answer OP's question to just 'enrich' SOME words.

Comment: All the text will be using the same font, size, boldnes...  thus it's not rich text.

Answer (score 28):

We can highlight the Text.
Right click the Text `Style Token->Using 1st Style`.By using this we can highlight Text.There will be upto 5 style.

Comment: This seems to highlight every appearance of the "token" (string; text).  Useful, though.  Now I'm wondering if i can define a "language" such that every space-terminated string preceded by a ! is displayed in bold...Done already.  "Markdown" is a language.  Nice.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily define your own language, where you can set a list of keywords. Each keyword has a font-type, color, size and so on..

This menu can be found under Language > Define your language...

Answer (score 3):

You can use a language called Markdown to get benefit of basic text processing feature like Bold, Italics, Underline and Strikethrough. In order to do that, go to Top Menu > Language > Markdown (Preinstalled).

**Enable Support for Strikethrough in Notepad++**:

```
1. Download the font BPtypewrite (https://www.1001fonts.com/download/bptypewrite.zip) or any other font that support strikethrough option by default.
2. Extract zip file then install individual font files by right clicking on it and from context menu hit the install option. Check details here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-font-b7c5f17c-4426-4b53-967f-455339c564c1
3. Open Notepad++ > Go to Top Menu > Language > User Defined Language > Define your language > This will open a popup window
4. Update the popup form as mentioned below -
a. User language: Select "Markdown (preinstalled)" from dropdown
b. Click on "Operators & Delimiters" tab
c. Modify Delimiter 8 style option as below
Open: ~~
Escape: \
Close: ~~
d. Click on Styler > This will open Styler Dialog
e. Update "Font options" as below -
Name: BPtypewriteStrikethrogh
Size: 10
f. Click on "OK" button
```

**Testing**:

1. Now open a new file in Notepad++
2. Go to Top Menu > Language > Markdown (Preinstalled)
3. Type: ~~This is a strike through text~~
4. This will show text in Strikethrough font.
5. Tested version: v8.5.5 (64-bit)

[Strikethrough working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iklJH.png)

Comment: This answer is a hidden gem. Works perfectly fine and explains a very useful concept of defining your own syntax. (Although I do not like the esthetics of the example strikethrough font – I can easily change it)