# Notepad++ Rtf Editing plugin

Tags: plugins, notepad++, rtf

Is there a plug-in for Notepad++ that does rtf highlighting?  To clarify, I mean when one opens an rtf file as plain text, is there a plugin that highlights rtf statements (like "{\rtf...}", "{\colortbl...}", and etc.) like it does with c++, c#, html, and etc. along with the ability to collapse blocks of rtf statements like an xml file?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Good news every-one! I found a UDL for RTF [here](https://github.com/nakohdo/NPP.RTF/blob/master/userDefineLang_RTF.xml).

Found it via this [link](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=User_Defined_Language_Files).

**[Edited 2 Aug 2016]** The list of User-Defined Languages is now available at this address: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/userDefinedLanguages/blob/master/udl-list.md

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: I don't know, and probably not.

Long answer: this is sort of a duplicate question; a related answer is yonder:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331753/topic/3445473

Re:
[Plugin for NotePad++ for rich text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065138/plugin-for-notepad-for-rich-text)